Save output of loop in single table in oracl SQL
I want to go through a for loop in sql and save the output of every loop in a single table.
declare
   type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(10);
   array array_t := array_t(4, 6, 7);

begin
   for i in 1..array.count 
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line(array(i)+1);
       dbms_output.put_line(array(i)+10);
      
   end loop;
   
end;

This code gives me 2 lines of output every iteration. i would like to save them in a single table, but can't seem to find the function to 'append'?
My wanted output is the following:
Table:
5
14
7
16
8
17


Your wording is slightly confusing... Do you mean you want to insert the values into a database table? Or are you just trying to format your output, using the string concatenation operator and padding to make the numbers line up?

There is no table involved here.

To display the output on the same line, you can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT (which doesn't flush the output to a new line) instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (which does):
declare
   type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(10);
   array array_t := array_t(4, 6, 7);
begin
   for i in 1..array.count 
   loop
       dbms_output.put(array(i)+1);
       dbms_output.put(' ');
       dbms_output.put_line(array(i)+10);
   end loop;
end;
/

or you can use a single DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and string concatenation:
declare
   type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(10);
   array array_t := array_t(4, 6, 7);
begin
   for i in 1..array.count 
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line((array(i)+1) || ' ' || (array(i)+10));
   end loop;
end;
/

Which both output:
5 14
7 16
8 17


If you want a result set then you can use SQL (rather than PL/SQL):
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE + 1 AS value1,
       COLUMN_VALUE + 10 AS value2
FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(4, 6, 7))

Which outputs:



VALUE1
VALUE2




5
14


7
16


8
17



fiddle
